# Error when attempting to view the tour's revision history

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, revisions-list, tour

On Latin.SE, I am getting a 404 error when clicking any of the three "history" links on the [tour page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour).  That is, this:

> [image: Top of the tour page, clicking history link]

Gives this:

> [image: 404]

All three editable sections have a revision history with two revisions or more, and all three give an error.  The actual links are [1](https://latin.stackexchange.com/posts/737/revisions), [2](https://latin.stackexchange.com/posts/738/revisions), and [3](https://latin.stackexchange.com/posts/739/revisions).

Comment: @ShadowWizard Hmm; when I click edit I get an inline edit box, not that message, and your direct edit link works too (but I'm a mod on Latin).  I wasn't aware that changes on the tour were subject to approval; I don't see any indication of that.

Comment: Hmm... so it means that error message is just generic, and pointless in this case. Doesn't really matter since non-mods should never visit such a link. Anyway, you get that error you mention when submitting the edit?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, I just made a trivial edit and it went through without an error.  I only get the error when clicking the "history" link; the edit link seems to work fine.

Comment: You mean you get error when trying to view revisions? I see them just fine, try to visit the links in Private/Incognito mode of the browser and see what happens

Comment: @ShadowWizard I get the same error in icognito mode.  We're talking about the same history link, right?  The one in my first screenshot?

Comment: Only mods see the link in the tour page itself, but I did click the link you posted yes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Okay, interesting.  I get the same behavior clicking the link on the tour page, and clicking the links in this post, in chrome and in chrome incognito.

Comment: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/468012/find-edits-by-post-type?PostTypes=7) returns revision histories that moderators on that site can’t see, but everyone else can. (Confirmed for scifi.SE, at least.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We were not handling the tour post type when showing revisions for moderators properly (an oversight during creation of the post redaction tool).

I have fixed this issue - will be with you in the next build (rev 2016.5.20.3597).