# Site moderators can't see the history of the FAQ page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderator-abilities, site-faq

The now-retired FAQ page for SE sites still has a publicly visible revision history, e.g.:

- [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/1585/revisions) for SFF SE
- [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/5956/revisions) for German SE
- etc.

Publicly visible, that is, **except to moderators of the site in question**. For instance, I can't view the SFF post linked above: it gives me an ["Oops! Something Bad Happened!"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/1585/revisions) page. It seems very peculiar to have a post which is visible to nearly every member of the site, or even without being logged in at all, but invisible to those few users  who can normally see *more* pages than other users.

Presumably (?) this is something to do with the fact that these pages used to be editable only by moderators, and when this permission was changed, somebody went too far and took away visibility as well as editability. Obviously it's an extremely low-priority bug, but also a weird and unusual one.

Comment: [tag:moderator-abilities]: *a subset of privileges available to moderators and users with high reputation.* Can I tag this [tag:moderator-disabilities], for the subset of privileges ***not*** available to moderators?

Comment: Can you see these? [election](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/10044/revisions), [about](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/29470/revisions), [another about page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/30577/revisions). Those last two are for the tour, I guess.

Comment: @anaranjada Nope, all of those just give me an Enterprise facepalm.

Comment: Looks like you can't see any [revisions of edit type 7](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/468012/find-edits-by-post-type?PostTypes=7) (WikiPlaceholder) then.

Comment: I hope the fix doesn't involve taking away my ability to see those revisions. *gasp*

Comment: @anaranjada I can see all of those...

Comment: @Zizouz212 because you aren't a mod on SF&F.

Comment: @Zizouz212: Pretty sure anaranjada is referring to their ability as a non-mod on *all* of those sites to see those; I can see http://opensource.stackexchange.com/posts/1538/revisions, for example, but I would assume you can't, being a diamond there. Letting you see that but taking it away from me and other non-mods would be a bit irritating as a bug fix.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of the following: [Error when attempting to view the tour's revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278450/300411)

Comment: [Apparently fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278450/error-when-attempting-to-view-the-tours-revision-history/279475#279475).