# Error when viewing revision history for Help Center article as a moderator

Tags: bug, moderators, help-center, revisions-list, 500-server-error

When I visit this revision list: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/66740/revisions, which for regular users looks like a history for the [participate in Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege, I get an error page:

[image]

It looks a bit like [Error when attempting to view the tour's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278450/295232) but these pages aren't editable by ♦ moderators. I can view all individual revisions like https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/66740/8.

Comment: It looks like the old privilege wiki page from before those were transitioned to being part of the help center.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog: Yep – it's definitely not the revision history of the current [participate in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege page; that revision history is located [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/199022/revisions). I think only CMs/staff and mods can see that revision history page.

Comment: If those posts are outdated, perhaps the simplest way to fix this bug is to purge them from the database :)